# Can't add device in VMware

Tags: windows-xp, vmware

I want to add a printer in my Windows XP guest OS. But I can't add the device because the add button in settings are grayed-out. Here is my problem picture:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Specify your vmware app, including version.

Comment: It looks like *all* controls are grayed out.  Verify that your user has write permissions to the VM's `.vmx` file and that it isn't read-only.